# How to identify multiple tooltip by css class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tooltip

I've used this [tooltip](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) at my webpage. My problem is, I'm using multiple styled and functional tooltip. So, I've to identify them by unique class name. For example, I've two tooltips:

```
<div class="tooltip" title="First Tooltip<span class='close'></span>"> 
        This div has a tooltip when you hover over it!
</div>
<div class="tooltip-1" title="<a href='#'>Second Tooltip</a>"> 
        This div has a tooltip too when you hover over!
</div>
```

I can make their function different by calling them with their class name:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    interactive: true,
    contentAsHTML: true,
});

$('.tooltip-1').tooltipster({
    interactive: true,
    contentAsHTML: true,
    position: 'bottom'
});
```

**But, I can't make their style different by their class name**. For example, I'm trying apply different style at my second tooltip by css. But, it's not working!

```
.tooltip-1 .tooltipster-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}
.tooltip-1 .tooltipster-default .tooltipster-content {
    padding: 0;
}
.tooltip-1 .tooltipster-content a {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display: block;
    color: #333;
}
```

So, **how can I apply different style in my second tooltip**?

[My fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/14/)

Comment: what about the a custom theme for each of them?

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution. Thanks :) http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/16/

Answer (score 1):

Just use 2 classes,..

```
<div class="tooltip tooltipStyle_1"></div>
<div class="tooltip tooltipStyle_2"></div>
```

Then style both secondary classes the way you want.

Also,... it might be working,.. but

```
<div title="bla <someTag>bla</someTag>">
```

Can't you do that differently?

Comment: Check your syntax, it definitely should! ".tooltip .tooltipStyle_*{..}" will not work, ".tooltipStyle_*{}" will!

Comment: first of all, I can't keeping same class in two divs as I've to make their function different too. And with same class it can't be possible. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/15/ I've applied     position: 'bottom at second div(last line of Javascript at fidle. Remove, tooltip from <div class="tooltip tooltip-1" and it'll work!). But, it can't get that function for the same class. Besides this, css is not working too!

Comment: $('.tooltip.tooltip-1').tooltipster({}) will indeed not work.
Just like the CSS, you should exclude .tooltip,.. so jQuery('.tooltip-1').myfunc(); or jQuery('.tooltip').myfunc();